# Window.onUnload inconsistently sends results to server

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload, onunload

I am trying to have the user get an alert when they try to leave the page, and make a post request if they leave, if not, do nothing. Here is my code (using JQuery):

```js
$(window).on("unload", function() { 
    $.post("/delete-room", {
        roomID: roomId
    });
});
$(window).on("beforeunload", function() { 
    return true
})
```

I (my servers) sometimes get the post request, but only about 1/5 times when I close the tab/unload the page. Is there a reason for this inconsistency? Thanks

Comment: Something on your server-side code which you do not show? Plus if user has their browser configs set where "nothing" will run javascript-wise on window / tab closed, you have no control.

Comment: @GetSet I can see sometimes I receive the requests, and I do not have any browser settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately making ajax call in an `unload` or `onBeforenUnload` event handler is not reliable. Most of the calls never reach the backend. Consider using [sendBeacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) instead.

```
$(window).on("unload", function() { 
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('roomID', roomId);
    navigator.sendBeacon("/delete-room", formdata);
});
```

The browser will `POST` the data without preventing or delaying, whatever is happening (closing tab or window, moving to a new page, etc.).

Comment: Thanks so much! Now the post calls are reaching the server consistently, however, the server outputs the body as `{}`. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: (note that I am trying to send JSON to the server). Thanks!

Comment: I think data have to be passed as [formdata](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData).

Comment: I edited my response to fix the way to pass data to the `sendBeacon()` function because JSON data are not supported.

Comment: Thanks! How would I read this server-side?

Comment: This depends on the language used by your backend... Read it as you usually do it for a HTML form posted the standard way.